# Javascript replace function is not working as expected with special character

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update a div tag with new metadata in a file and I am using the replace function to do this job ,but is not working as expected , it is adding junk  tag in the middle.

I am trying this below code.

```js
let str = `<div data-bind="style:{'background-color':typeof(CalEventBgColor)!=='undefined'? CalEventBgColor:''},css:typeof(CalEventType)!=='undefined'? 'event '+ CalEventType:'event',attr:{ title:dynamicTitle ,id: CalEventId+'$'+$parentContext.$index()+'$'+$index()+$parents[1].componentid}" role="button" tabindex="0">
</div>`;
let oldVal = `<div data-bind="style:{'background-color':typeof(CalEventBgColor)!=='undefined'? CalEventBgColor:''},css:typeof(CalEventType)!=='undefined'? 'event '+ CalEventType:'event',attr:{ title:dynamicTitle ,id: CalEventId+'$'+$parentContext.$index()+'$'+$index()+$parents[1].componentid}" role="button" tabindex="0">`;
let newVal =`<div :class="[[typeof(CalEventType)!=='undefined'? 'event '+ CalEventType:'event']]" :title="[[dynamicTitle]]" :id="[[CalEventId+'$'+$parentContext.$index()+'$'+$index()+$parents[1].componentid]]" :style="[[{ 'background-color':typeof(CalEventBgColor)!=='undefined'? CalEventBgColor:''}]]" role="button" tabindex="0">`;
console.log(str.replace(oldVal,newVal));
```

Basically if you see the :id property it is broken with junk character, please let me know if we can do something for this.

Comment: Can you reduce the size of the example string, so to focus on the essence of the problem? I don't see which junk character you are referring to.

Comment: It is giving output like this ref value of :id prop <div :class="[[typeof(CalEventType)!=='undefined'? 'event '+ CalEventType:'event']]" :title="[[dynamicTitle]]" :id="[[CalEventId+'
</div>+$parentContext.$index()+'
</div>+$index()+$parents[1].componentid]]" :style="[[{ 'background-color':typeof(CalEventBgColor)!=='undefined'? CalEventBgColor:''}]]" data-bind="attr:{'aria-describedby':'descr'+ CalEventId+'
</div>+$parentContext.$index()+'
</div>+$index()+$parents[1].componentid},click:$parents[1].handleClick,event:{keypress:$parents[1].handleKeyPress}" role="button" tabindex="0">
</div>

Comment: Agreed, a [mcve] should include just enough code to replicate the issue. Your strings are so long that it's difficult to see what is happening.

Comment: Updated sample code with reduced code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `$` is used to replace substring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#description

You just have to add one more dollar sign before every dollar. This string `CalEventId+'$'+$parentContext.$index()+'$'+$index()`  should look like this `CalEventId+'$$'+$$parentContext.$$index()+'$$'+$index()`

Comment: I tried this code to replace all $ with $$ but is not replacing  let oldval = '$data';
console.log(oldval.replaceAll('$','$$'));

Comment: It happens because of the same problem: `$$` also is used to replace substrings. So you can write it in this way: `oldval.replaceAll('$','$$$$')`. First and third `$` will say, that the second one and the fourth one are just symbols.

So we need to use 4 dollars to make it looks like 2 dollars to finally get 1 dollar

Comment: Tried this way and it worked , thanks for helping it solved my original issue  -> let oldval = '$data$';
oldval =oldval.replaceAll(/\$/g, '$$$$')

console.log(oldval);